# How to actually use pymongo ChangeStreams with Flask in a non-blocking way?

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

I am learning flask and PyMongo right now and came across ChangeStreams. I do understand how ChangeStreams work but I have only worked with them in Node and Express. I have implemented  ChangeStreams in my Flask app as following:

```
with ms.db.collection.watch() as stream:
    for change in stream:
        print(change)
```

On the official docs pages, it says that it's a **blocking** method. But how would I go about in making it **non-blocking**? Because currently my ChangeStream logic is in a different file and I import it into the server.py file. So when it never goes past that import and the Flask App doesn't start at all. Below is my server.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import mongo_starter as ms
import changestream as cs


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
```

Below is my ChangeStream.py

```py
import mongo_starter as ms 

with ms.db.collection.watch() as stream:
    for change in stream:
        print(change)
```

Below is my MongoStarter.py that actually initiates the connection to Mongo

```py
import pymongo
import mongo_config as mc

print(mc.data_header)
try:
    print('Connecting to Database...')
    mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(mc.mongo_url)
    db = mongo_client['PyMongo']
    collection = db['Test Data']
    print("Connection to Database Successful!")
except pymongo.errors.InvalidURI:
    print('Error Connecting to Database')
```

When I run the app using nodemon it prints the following to the output.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `python server.py`
----------------- MONGO CONNECTION LOG --------------------
Connecting to Database...
Connection to Database Successful!
```

So it never actually goes past the change stream method. How can I make it so it worked in an async way? I have looked at asyncio, but wanted to see if there was any way to implement it without using asyncio.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? I mean, what is the reason for opening a change stream upon starting your flask server?

Comment: One trivial solution can be just placing `app.run()` before importing your `changestream`. In this case, you may want to create multiple threads to be able to respond to http requests while having your change stream opened. Does this satisfy your requirement?

Comment: I want to receive real-time updates from the server. For example, if someone inserts a user, I want to get that update from the change stream so I can display on all client instances.

Comment: @AliTou I already tried creating multiple threads. So in the beginning I had two threads. One for app.run() and other for starting the change stream. But that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: You might want to consider having 2 separate apps and handling the updates using pub/sub using RabbitMQ or similar.

Comment: So is there no way to do it with one app? And I’m asking that because I want to keep it simple.

Comment: Let's assume you can do it one app, what's your plan / approach for letting the flask app know that a change has occurred?

Comment: When a change has occurred what I will do is  I will store the change to a variable in changestream.py and then access it in server.py and then show it in the index.html.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?  \