# MongoDB Change Stream: How to keep it alive?

Tags: python, mongodb, changestream

I've been trying to implement a change stream that monitors a Mongo collection for new documents.  While simple to setup for catching one change, I don't understand how to keep the process running indefinitely.

```
db = pymongo_util.get_collection("DataDB","XYZ_Collection")
stream = db.watch(full_document="updateLookup"):
document = next(stream)  # it blocks here until a change happens.  Prints the change, and program ends
print(document)
```

My goal is to create a 'listener' for the database.   Listen for new documents, and process those new documents.  I'm not sure if asyncio is the way to go, threading, or if its something basic I'm missing.

It looks like I'm not the only one to ask, but none seem to have an answer:

1. [How to actually use pymongo ChangeStreams with Flask in a non-blocking way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391256/how-to-actually-use-pymongo-changestreams-with-flask-in-a-non-blocking-way)
2. [Watch MongoDB Change Streams in Python asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68980881/watch-mongodb-change-streams-in-python-asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

Both referred question were about how to implement asynchronous behaviour. If you are happy with blocking reads, just loop over the iterator:

```
for document in stream:
    print(document)
```

It won't run indefinitely of course, but for some significant time. You will need to wrap it in try-except to catch cursor errors, and use `resume_token` to continue reading from where it aborted, but it's another story.

Comment: but thats the thing, I need it to run continuously

Comment: but it will. Exceptions .. . well, exceptional. They can happen for number of reasons beyond your control, you just need to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```py
cursor = db.collection.watch()
while True:
    document = next(cursor)
    # do stuff
```

If you want it to work like traditional database triggers, you will need to run this continuously. It's important to note that while you can run this as an always-running python process, processes die pretty easily. An alternative would be to run this every minute or so via a cron-job.

You will need to save the [resume token](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#std-label-change-stream-resume) of the collection in a separate collection and pass it the next time you run this process

```py
# assuming you saved the token the last time you ran this
resume_token = db.progress_colection.findOne(
    {collectionName: 'name'}
)['resumeToken']
cursor = db.collection.watch(
    resume_after=resume_token
)

# do stuff
resume_token = cursor.resume_token

# save the token to the collection
```

Answer (score 1):

To run continuously you can use the "with" statement on the "watch" method:

```
pipeline = [{"$match": {"operationType": "insert"}}]

with db[collection_name].watch(pipeline=pipeline) as stream:
    print("Listening for changes...")

    for change in stream:
        print("Processed change:", change)
```

There is an example on the pymongo documentation which also uses the "resume token": https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/change_stream.html